# CSS focus. Can't get it to change a label field

Tags: css, focus, field

I am trying to get a focus on a field change the color of a text, but whatever I try: it is not working. Below is the HTML:

```css
.register-section input:focus + .register-section label[for=signup_username] {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="register-section" id="basic-details-section">
<h4>Account Details</h4>
<label for="signup_username">Username (required)</label>
<input type="text" name="signup_username" id="signup_username" value="" />
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `+` adjacency operator can only be used to select DOM nodes *following* the initial selector (CSS selectors can only resolve in this direction). As such, because your label is *before* your input in your html, you cannot select it on the `:focus` state of the input using CSS.

To fix this, you will need to change your HTML to reverse the order of the elements, and adjust your CSS to change their display order, then select as appropriate:

```css
.register-section label[for=signup_username] {
  float: left;
}
.register-section input:focus + label[for=signup_username] {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="register-section" id="basic-details-section">
  <h4>Account Details</h4>
  <input type="text" name="signup_username" id="signup_username" value="" />
  <label for="signup_username">Username (required)</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for those who wish to achieve the same result using jQuery, target the `focus` and `blur` events of the input field to change the color of the label:

```
$('#signup_username').on('focus blur', function(e){
    var label = $("label[for=signup_username]");
    if (e.type == 'focus'){
        label.css('color','#FFF');
    }
    else {
        label.css('color','#000');    
    }
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wc249f5u/)